# DeleteSubKey UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I'm trying to write a quick app to modify some registry keys.  When I'm browsing via RegEdit, I can modify and delete the keys with no problems.

But when I try to use `RegistryKey.DeleteSubKey()` it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Is there any way to gain the privileges to do this? Also, why would there be a problem if my user account obviously has access to make the changes?

Edit:

Here's some code

```
RegistryKey reg;

try
{
    reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BaseKey);
    reg.DeleteSubKey("{" + Item.Guid.ToString() + "}");
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And how are opening the key before the call to delete? Can you show the few lines of code before you call deletesubkey?

Comment: You could be refused when trying to delete the sub-key if you have an open handle to it (as curtisk suggested), or possibly if the key is not empty of values...

Comment: No open handle that I can see, and it does have values, though I switched to DeleteSubKeyTree and still got the same issue.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try this instead, open it initially as read/write instead of read-only:

```
RegistryKey reg;

try
{
    reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BaseKey, true); //<--over here!
    reg.DeleteSubKey("{" + Item.Guid.ToString() + "}");
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *massive smack to the forehead* - Thanks!

Comment: I forget to do this every single time.

Comment: For Compact Framework users, try: **reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"\", true);**

Comment: Optional boolean parameters are such a code smell