# Set Registry value throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#

I have a C# application and I am trying to edit a service through the registry. I am using a manifest file that requires administrator privileges to run my application. Despite that, this code throws

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Cannot write to the registry key.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey ("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\Tomcat7");
key.SetValue ("Start", 2, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Does anybody have any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: This might help , looks like you are opening the key read only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732126/deletesubkey-unauthorizedaccessexception Google is your friend.

Comment: Sure enuff, before you pop a question on here googleing works great, way faster than stackoverflow even at it's best... I literally just copied your subject, pasted it into google and the answer was the 2nd link :)

Comment: Thanks for that Eric, too bad I did do some searching and didn't come across it. Everything I did find was about the need to elevate permissions.

Comment: It's a Classic Case of Ask the duck... :) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might help ,

[Link to similar issue on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732126/)

looks like you are opening the key read only.

Answer (score 34):

Follow the following code, note the additional `true` argument:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\Tomcat7",true);
key.SetValue("Start", 2, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```